# How to convert a file name when using Java Mail API

Tags: java, file, email

I wrote an adapter between an SQL database and mail server. I used a POP3 connection.
Thereafter, I encountered the following problem - when the adapter receives  a Russian file name this error occurs.
Example input file name: `=?UTF-8?B?0KHQutGA0LjQv9C60LAg0JzQsNGA0LjRjy5kb2N4?=`

 The coded format is Base64. I tried to convert Base64 to UTF-8 but it did not solve the problem.

My code:

```
if (contentType.contains("multipart"))
            {
                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                for (int partCount = 0; partCount<numberOfParts; partCount++)
                {
                    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                    if (!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition()))
                    {
                        //this part is attachment
                        continue;

                    }

                        //String fileName = part.getFileName();
                        String fileName = part.getFileName().toString();
                        if (fileName.contains("UTF-8"))
                        {
                            byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(fileName.getBytes());
                            fileName = new String(decoded, "UTF-8");
                        }
                        attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                        part.saveFile("d:/" + File.separator + fileName);
                        //this part may be the message content
                        messageContent = part.getContent().toString();

                }
                if (attachFiles.length() > 1)
                {
                    attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length()-2);
                }
            }
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Try to convert only this part `0KHQutGA0LjQv9C60LAg0JzQsNGA0LjRjy5kb2N4`

Comment: If I tryed this part, it's will work. But this code don't returned **String fileName = part.getFileName().toString();** this value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filename isn't a base64 encoded string. It is encoded as defined by [RFC 2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt).

Don't try to decode such strings by hand. Use solid libraries like [Apache Mime4j](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/) for encoding/decoding mime messages.

Add Mime4j to your project (here Maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-mime4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Use `org.apache.james.mime4j.codec.DecoderUtil` for decoding quoted-printable strings:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String decoded = DecoderUtil.decodeEncodedWords("=?UTF-8?B?0KHQutGA0LjQv9C60LAg0JzQsNGA0LjRjy5kb2N4?=", null);
    assertEquals("Скрипка Мария.docx", decoded);
}
```