# Javamail and Scandinavian letters in filename

Tags: java, character-encoding, jakarta-mail, multipart

I got a multipart message from backend which I tried to read. The message is for example like this:

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name*=UTF-8''jyrkik%C3%AF%C2%BF%C2%BFteinen.jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''jyrkik%C3%AF%C2%BF%C2%BFteinen.jpg
```

Filename is jyrkikäteinen.jpg. 
Always when there is scandinavian letters the filename is null even if I can see it in the message, but in other cases (filename doesn't include scandic letters) getFileName is working fine. In "normal" case the fileName part is like that:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hellsinski_header.png

 MimeBodyPart content = (MimeBodyPart)multipart.getBodyPart(n);
     if(content.getDisposition() !=null && content.getDisposition().equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT)){
     content.getFileName(); // This is always null if scandic letters in name
```

I tried to set property properties.setProperty("mail.mime.decodefilename", "true"), but it didn't help.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799061/how-to-convert-a-file-name-when-using-java-mail-api

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  The [newest versions](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) should handle this without the need to set any properties.  The filename parameter is encoded using RFC 2231.

Comment: BTW, this was the problem. <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6</version>